# How can I authenticate to GCP using a service account key that was uploaded (not generated)?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, authorization, service-accounts

Im writing a service that requires access to GCP services by different tenants.
My micro-service will run on different host (no GCP).
One of the constraints I have is to authorize api calls by using service account key.
Second constraint is that my micro-service is responsible for generating the key pair for the service account and share the public key with the tenant so they can upload it to their service account.

My current problem is that Im not able to find any documentation that explains how I can authenticate to GCP golang libraries using the key pair I have. All the documentation I have read always addresses the service account key authentication from the assumption that you will let GCP generate the key pair for you and you already have the json file with all the details required.

Documentation I have reviewed:

```
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries#adc
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#service-accounts
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-key
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/main/auth/id_token_from_service_account.go
```

Google libraries use a mechanism called Application Default Credentials that lets all their libraries find the credentials to use for authentication. Specifically in this scenario, ADC always requires a json file in order to get the details of the credentials.

The json file looks like the following:

```json
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "my-project",
    "private_key_id": "1ed3aae07f98f3e6da78ad308b41232133d006cf",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "<EMAIL HERE>",
    "client_id": "1234567890102",
    "auth_uri": "<GOOGLE AUTH URI HERE>",
    "token_uri": "<GOOGLE TOKEN URI HERE>",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "<SOME GOOGLE URL HERE>",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "<MORE GOOGLE URL HERE>",
    "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

So my question is, how can I build this json file from my generated key pair?
If this is no possible (GCP constraints), then why am I able to upload a key pair?
Is there any example out there someone could point me towards to help me with this scenario?

Any help is greatly appreciated

I have looked into all the GCP official documentation, the API reference and the Github script samples. None of them make reference to uploaded service account keys

Comment: If other host are Azure or AWS, you still not need a key...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I need to use an uploaded service account key because that is how the integration is designed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a some time to come back to this question. Thanks to @guillaume-blaquiere answer I started testing with a minimum required file.

And finally came up with this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "private_key": "<Your generated private_key.pem>",
  "client_email": "<service account email>",
}
```

These are the minimum required attributes for google SDK's to successfully authenticate to GCP

The private key must be the one used to generate the public key uploaded to GCP's service account.

In terms of the golang code, this information can be put into an structure and then parse that structure to json:

```
type JSONFile struct {
  Type     string `json:"type"`
  PrivKey  []byte `json:"private_key"`
  Email    string `json:"client_email"`
}
```

Then:

```
file := JSONFile{
    Type:        "service_account",
    PrivKey:  "<PK bytes here>",
    Email: "service-account-email@gcp.com",
}
result, err := json.Marshal(file)
if err != nil {
    panic(1)
}
credentials, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(context.Background(), result, secretmanager.DefaultAuthScopes()...)
if err != nil {
    panic(1)
}
projectsClient, err := resourcemanager.NewProjectsClient(context.Background(), option.WithCredentials(credentials))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [projects.serviceAccounts.keys.upload](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/upload) method.

Comment: The problem is not the upload of the key. The problem is that when a public key is uploaded it does not generate a json for me to use and there is no documentation at all in Google channels that explains how to work with a public key that was uploaded

Comment: But the upload returns a service account key, right? That's the key you should use. Does that not work?

Comment: You are correct in the sense that the REST api returns the data I need to build a json file and use it for authentication to other libraries. However, in my use case I can not upload the the key myself programatically. Instead the user must do it (most likely using the web console) and on that scenario, I dont get any json or proper values to use.

Comment: That clarifies the scenario a lot. What you describe is not possible for security reasons, I imagine. The same happens for Google generated keys. You get the JSON with the private key info when creating but you cannot get it again via any API.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and it seems working with so few update on a standard service account key file

```json
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "my-project",
    "private_key_id": "<the key ID returned by the upload api (last parameter of the 'name' uri)>",
    "private_key": "<Your generated private_key.pem>",
    "client_email": "<service account email>",
    "client_id": "<oauth2ClientId found with this command  gcloud iam service-accounts describe <service account email>>",
    "auth_uri": "<let it unchanged>",
    "token_uri": "<let it unchanged>",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "<let it unchanged>",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/ + <service account email with @ replaced by %40>",
    "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

I tested

- Access token
- Impersonated Access Token
- Identity token.

All worked with this service account key file structure.

*Note: You have a private key in it, keep it secure as much as you can!*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @guillaume-blaquiere. I have realized that I may need to ask certain parameters from the user in order to build the json file and use it as authentication (following DAC approach).